# pagemasking in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application i'm using menu...
when i click the menu item particular page will load in the center Frame.

Problem is it takes bit time... 
now i want to show a masking (message to let the users know that page is loading)
( As showing in the Image ) until the page loading
how to do this in Javascript

sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #content { display:none; }
</style>
<!-- Javascript that makes one div visible and hides another -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide() {
        document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</head>
<!-- calls the javascript function when the page is loaded -->
<body onload="showhide();">
<!-- div to be shown while the page is loading -->
<div id="load">
  <img src="http://www.photo-canvas.com/images/generic/loading_gif.gif" />
</div>
<!-- div to be shown when the page is loaded -->
<div id="content">
  [all the slow content]
</div>
```

Thank you........

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but shouldn't your showhide function be:

```
document.getElementById("load").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
```

Depending on what you are loading, this may or may not be the solution.  For example, I believe (but could be wrong) that onload does not take account of whether images are loaded.  It certainly wouldn't take account of AJAX content.

Perhaps an easier way to achieve this would be for your initial page to only contain the loading screen and the rest of the content to be loaded by AJAX.  With jQuery this is quite easy (this is an easy way to do it: http://api.jquery.com/load/)